# Weird error while compile Android project with build-tool version 27.0.3

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I didn't have any issue with

> Android Studio 3.0, 
>   Gradle 3.1.0, 
>   build-tool 25.0.3 
>   and Kotlin 1.2.10

Few days ago I receive the update popup in Android Studio many times, so I decided to upgrade it to latest version 3.1.2
After that, upon to request during gradle-sync and compile (it thrown errors), I upgrade the tools to:

> build-tool 27.0.3, 
>   compileSdkVersion 27
>   targetSdkVersion 27
>   gradle 3.1.0

Now I always get below error which can not fix myself after few days:

Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':sdk:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/TrueFileFilter
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 1s

I now even can not rollback to previous versions. If I change the build-tool back to `25.0.3` I got this error:

> The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (25.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (27.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.1.0. Android SDK Build Tools 27.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools. Update Build Tools version and sync project Open File

I spent a lot of time but can not resolve it myself so please help to take a look and tell me any mistake I made.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: have you tried removing `buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'` from your buid.gradle?

Comment: Yes, once I remove that line, it turn to use `27.0.3` by default and thown the first issue: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/TrueFileFilter`

Comment: If you are using `TrueFileFilter`, are you including `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'` in your build.gradle?

Comment: No I don't. @Sagar

Comment: I personally haven't used TrueFileFilter, but I had read somewhere that since its not part of official Android SDK you have to include  `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'` in your app level build.gradle. You can try it out. But it would be just a try and error since I don't have any official document stating it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this may help others, but I found the cause on my case.
One of libraries I am using already include `commons-io` already. I don't actually remember which one but I used to have another compiling problem with them last few months and I added below configuration to bypass:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'commons-io'
}
```

Now this configuration cause the problem I asked above, I tried to remove it and now everything fine again.